# Get the real values of environment variables on a remote machine in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wmi, environment-variables

I'm trying to get the **actual values** of **environment variables**.
This is what I have so far:

```
string query = string.Format("Select VariableValue From Win32_Environment Where Name = '{0}'", variableName);

using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
using (ManagementObject result = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().FirstOrDefault())
{
    if (result != null)
    return Convert.ToString(result["VariableValue"]);
}
```

That works, but here's the problem: passing **'windir' as name** gets **'%SystemRoot%' as value**. What I really **want** is the **actual path**, i.e. 'C:\Windows'.

I **tried** using **recursion** to get the **value of 'SystemRoot'** but **no matches** were found.

How can I make sure that the **real values** get returned?
Thx!

Comment: Why is %SystemRoot% not acceptable?  If you put that in a explorer window you would go to the installation directory of windows.  Because %SystemRoot% could be D:\Windows\ in theory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to expand environment variables remotely with .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031111/how-to-expand-environment-variables-remotely-with-net)

Comment: @ Ramhound: I'm writing a method that **runs a command** on a remote machine using **Win32_Process.Create**. **Environment variables don't** seem to **get recognized**, so I was looking to **replace them myself**. If there's way to **get them recognized automatically**, that would **also solve my problem**.

Answer (score 2):

For [system path variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#System_path_variables) (like `%SystemRoot%`) there's no convenient way.

You have to look for these values yourself by reading the corresponding registry values. Heres' a (not complete) list of some of these system variables:

- **%SystemRoot%**:

  ```
  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SystemRoot
  ```

  or

  ```
  select windowsdirectory from Win32_OperatingSystem
  ```
- **%SystemDrive%** can be determined by examining %SystemRoot%

Variables like **%AppData%** are user dependent and found under

```
HKEY_USERS\<user SID>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\AppData
```

Comment: That would get %SystemRoot% for me, but not **%ProgramFiles%** or others.
I suppose I'm looking for a remote version of Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable

Comment: @David: There is no remote version. An alternative would be to remotely execute `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`, e.g. by starting a program on the remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's creative at best but this seems to be the simplest solution:
Too much overhead perhaps?

```
        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\PsTools\PsExec.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\machineName cmd /c echo " + environmentVar;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.Start();
            return process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Comment: `Too much overhead perhaps?` Not at all. Especially when set against the overhead of chasing down rabbit trails trying to resolve recursive variables: `%ComSpec% = %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe`. What a nightmare. I was about to give up when I spotted your answer. Nice trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Win32_Environment for this, but you can use remote registry.

```
RegistryKey environmentKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(
      RegistryHive.LocalMachine, "\\server");
RegistryKey key = environmentKey.OpenSubKey(
      @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment", false);
string value = (string)key.GetValue("System");
```

Answer (score -2):

use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)`

Comment: The question title says on a remote machine.