# Getting remote machine's WINDOWS path

Tags: c#

I need to list files from a remote machine's WINDOWS directory. The programming language I am using is C# and the target OSs are Windows XP and Windows Server 2003. Right now what I am doing is:

```
filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("\\\\" + machineName + "\\c$\\WINDOWS");
```

Now, there might be instances where the WINDOWS directory is installed on a drive other than "C:\". This of course would pose problems with the above code.

Anyone got a better solution?

Also, another requirement is for me to read kb*log files (residing in the WINDOWS directory for OS < Vista). Any recommendations as to how I should implement this? I am thinking of using a StreamReader unless there is a better alternative.

TIA!

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031111/how-to-expand-environment-variables-remotely-with-net/5031419#5031419

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the remote machine's registry, you could read the `PathName` variable from the following key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.System);
```

or

```
Environment.SystemDirectory
```

Comment: That would work if the application is executed on the local machine. However, what I am looking for is a way to retrieve paths of special folders from the remote machine. Thank you though. The registry location as suggested above would work with minor string modifications.

Comment: oh didn't read it right... so i think the first answer of [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031111/how-to-expand-environment-variables-remotely-with-net) will be helpful for you